# IIS7 on localhost: sub-domain can't be seen externally only by local machine

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7, subdomain, localhost

I have setup a site on localhost (Win7 32bit) that can be accessed locally or by other machines on our network using `http://meeting-room` however the sub-domain `http://admin.meeting-room` can only be seen by the machine hosting the site.

The name of the machine hosting the site is `meeting-room` as per above.

Could anyone shed any light on where I might start exploring or if there is an obvious mistake I have made?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the subdomain is in DNS as well, you can test this by seeing if admin.meeting-room.yourdomain.com pings.

If it does not, go to your domain controller and add this host.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have pinged meeting-room with success but admin.meeting-room failed. I am hosting from Windows 7 rather than Windows server, is the domain controller aspect still relavent? If so where might i find it?

Comment: Well, you can edit the DNS on your local machine by installing it in Windows Features and adding the IP address of the DC and then you will need to add an entry in the forward lookup zone.

Comment: That is if your machines are on a network with an AD. If not, the reason could be that the Win7 machine hosting the site is actually named "meeting-room", this would mean that other machines on the same local network would be able to see the meeting-room machine, because it advertises itself in the workgroup. To solve the problem in this setup, you could add the ip-address of the meeting-room machine to the host-file of all the other machines (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)

Answer (score 0):

it's all about the DNS
you have 2 solution to fix this 
1- add each subdomain in the records of your DNS
2- add *.domain.com in the records of  your subdomain, this will point all the subdomains to the ip address you are mentioning

hope this was helpfull